# Why does the context `this` in nested function change?

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

I have a basic fundamental question. I execute the below code.

```
var app = {
  x: 10,

  start: function() {
    window.setTimeout(this.callback.bind(this), 10);
  },

  callback: function() {

    function print() {
      console.log('p '+ this.x);
    }

    console.log('c '+ this.x);
    print();

  }
};

app.start();
```

You can execute this code on [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/focuguciko/edit?js,console)

I expect it to output `c 10` and `p 10`. Instead it outputs `c 10` and `p undefined`. On further inspection, seems like `this` inside `print()` points to `window` object. Why would this be happening?

Answer (score 0):

Because when you are calling `print`, you are not using any context, so `this` inside print refers to the window object.

You can pass a custom context to `print` by using `.call()` like

```js
var app = {
  x: 10,

  start: function() {
    window.setTimeout(this.callback.bind(this), 10);
  },

  callback: function() {

    function print() {
      snippet.log('p ' + this.x);
    }

    snippet.log('c ' + this.x);
    print.call(this);

  }
};

app.start();
```

```html
<!-- Provides the `snippet` object, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/242144/134069 -->
<script src="http://tjcrowder.github.io/simple-snippets-console/snippet.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are declared a global function inside the object. You can change to this:

```
callback: function() {

   this.print = function(){
      console.log('p '+ this.x);
   }

   this.print()

 }
```

Jsfiddle working: http://jsfiddle.net/rsf6gmr2/

Answer (score -2):

You need to use `bind` to `print()` function, to make it works.

```
function print() {
    console.log('p '+ this.x);
}.bind(this)
```

Because without it every function has own `this` object linked to window.